# Merge two HTML element objects to be referenced collectively

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have variables like below. I am using this variable in many different places.

```
  var bed2 = $('.bed2');
var labelTwo = $('.label-two');
```

Now, let's say I need to use it as below

```
$('.bed2, .label-two').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

Definitely, I can do like below

```
bed2.css('background-color', 'yellow');
labelTwo.css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

However, it feels like writting those two lines above feels yucky. Can those two lines be combined into one something like

```
bed2,labelTwo.css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

My question is about combining the variables `bed2`,`labelTwo` into one line.

Comment: I may have been not clear. Yes, there it is in one line. However, it then uses the .bed or .label-two. I want to use the variables bed2 or labelTwo. Is that possible?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: Hi @SLaks You have to be kidding me. I have been coding for long and never came across this. This is useful at times. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to reuse the `bed2`, and `labelTwo` variables just like you can use both of the elements that they are referring like `$(".bed2, label-two")`.

Yes, I think what you are looking for is [`$.merge`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) which can help you merge both HTML elements object into an array of HTML elements which can be referenced collectively for both of those elements like below.

```
$.merge(bed2,labelTwo).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
```

you can see in the console using statement `console.log($(".bed2,.label-two"),$.merge(bed2,labelTwo));` to see if they are identicle or not , its just the collection of html elements that is returned in both cases.

see a demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var bed2 = $(".bed2");
  var label2 = $(".label-two");

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $.merge(bed2, label2).css({
      'background': '#f8f8f8',
      'border': '1px solid red',
    });

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bed2">
  BED
</div>

<div class="label-two">
  LABEL
</div>

<button>click me to add some css to both divs above atonce</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Change `,` to `:`

Current is:

```
$('.bed2, .label-two').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Change to:

```
$('.bed2, .label-two').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

Example here:

```js
$('.bed2, .label-two').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bed2">
  Hello
</div>

<div class="label-two">
  World
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for picking that up. However, I was actually looking for the add jquery function. But, yes you are right. I do have a syntax error

Comment: Actually you can use the first syntax. The braces-colon syntax is useful if you want to set multiple attributes like: `{'background-color':'yellow', 'border-color':'black'}`.

Comment: you can use the comma separator to when passing as parameters to update a single property, and the OP wants to update the elements using a single reference or statement, for both the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, it's just a little tricky. A jQuery can take an array of elements. [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) returns the elements found by a selector as an array. Concat the arrays and there you go.

Added an example using SLaks answer.

```js
var bed2 = $('.bed2');
var labelTwo = $('.label-two');

bed2.css('background-color', 'yellow');
labelTwo.css('background-color', 'yellow');

$('#theButton').click(function() {
  $(bed2.get().concat(labelTwo.get())).css('background-color', 'green');
});

$('#theButton2').click(function() {
  bed2.add(labelTwo).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

```css
.bed2, .label-two {
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bed2"></div>
<div class="label-two"></div>
<button id="theButton">Click green</button>
<button id="theButton2">Click blue</button>
```

Comment: Why to make things complicated when you can do the same in simple way? Check my answer please

Comment: @VicJordan Because your answer doesn't actually answer the question. "My question is about combining the variables". Using that "hard coded" css selector is just fine for the simplistic and contrived example we are working with. However in a complex situation where you might not know the actual selector that was used to construct the jQuery object, how would you make your solution work?